# TeXstudio: glossaries \gls command doesn't list label choices

Tags: glossaries, texstudio

I've been using glossaries for at least a year and in my case keeping the acronyms in a separate file. Some time in the last several months it ceased listing the label choices with the `\gls` command.
I'm working in TeXstudio 2.10.2. I assume the change wouldn't be due to updating TeXstudio? Even this mwe from the beginner's guide does not list the label choices when I write `\gls`. Though as I've never stored acronyms inside the document .tex file I appreciate I don't know if that functionality exists when prepared that way. I consider myself a LaTeX beginner so am possibly missing the obvious. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\begin{document}
  First use: \gls{svm}. Second use: \gls{svm}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a question about editor behaviour, in particular texstudio.

Comment: Do you still have this problem in version 2.10.8? With your MWE, for me `\gls` expands to `\gls{label}` and `\gls{svm}`.

Answer (score 2):

Without `acronym` as the option to `glossaries` → no acronyms

Without `\makeglossaries` in the preamble → no acronyms

Both are missing in the `MWE` (the `\printacronyms` is not necessary, I added it just to show them)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\begin{document}
  First use: \gls{svm}. Second use: \gls{svm}.
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian. Unfortunately that's not the problem I'm facing. In the past I could type `\gls{` and I'd then get a list of acronyms to chose from. That is now absent.

Comment: @mfolkes: Well, what's the point now? I can't help about weird settings of TeXStudio and all of those strange editors. I don't use them and that's most likely the cause it works ;-)

Comment: Well that response is based on two assumptions: 1. That TeXStudio is the problem, which hasn't yet been demonstrated. 2. That TeXStudio possesses some quality of strangeness - whatever that is.

Comment: @mfolkes: I know that it works -- as such it's an answer. I can't look into your computer and fix the settings. Please consider also, that `glossaries` has been updated multiple times during the last year.